# Error while trying to install ruby for rail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I am trying to install Ruby on Rails using https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm tutorial, but when I get to the part where I need to install Ruby 1.9.3 it always display this error message.

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.04/i386/ruby-1.9.3-p385.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary     rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/eldin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385, this may take a   while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p385 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p385, this may take a while depending on your     connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p385 - #extracted to /home/eldin/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p385 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p385 - #configuring
ruby-1.9.3-p385 - #compiling
Error running 'make', please read /home/eldin/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p385/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

I can not use Ruby interpretor, so Ruby is not installed.

I am using Ubuntu OS.

EDIT:

```
/home/eldin/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p385/make.log
```

Content of make.log

```
CC = gcc
LD = ld
LDSHARED = gcc -shared
CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=write-strings -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=implicit-function-declaration  -fPIC 
XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
CPPFLAGS =   -I/home/eldin/.rvm/usr/include -I. -I.ext/include/i686-linux -I./include -I.
DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.1.9  
SOLIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm  
linking miniruby
vm.o: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [miniruby] Error 1
```

Comment: What errors are in the log file? It almost sounds like you might not have a compiler (i.e. gcc) installed.

Comment: have you done this part? `please read /home/eldin/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p385/make.log`

Comment: @jvnill I have read make.log, but I dont understand it

Comment: you should include that in the question :)

Comment: @jvnill I have included make.log in the question

Comment: sorry, cant find anything on the net regarding your error. all i get is an nvidia video card issue in ubuntu

Comment: Perhaps you have lefovers from some previous build. Did you run any of the build commands as root at any point? If so you need to do: `sudo rm -rf ~/.rvm` to completely remove the `.rvm` folder. Then start over.

Comment: to really install ruby you need to write sudo at the start of each command

Comment: @Casper currently I am trying to reinstall with rvm reinstall 1.9.3 command, if ti fails I will try your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed : http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

It worked like a charm in the first go itself. Try following the steps mentioned in this blog.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed ruby 1.9.3 using rvm reinstall 1.9.3, and now it works without a problem.